# Prevent elements from moving when changing position to fixed dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm changing position of my menu to fixed on scroll with following code:

```
var $stickyEl = $('#sticky-menu');
var elementBeforeHeight = $('.startHandle').height();
$window.on('scroll', function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= elementBeforeHeight){
        $stickyEl.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        $stickyEl.removeClass('navbar-static-top');
    }
    else{
        $stickyEl.addClass('navbar-static-top');
        $stickyEl.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    }
});
```

It works but it has one little bug. The moment of change causes content after menu to jump closer to menu.  I guess this is some kind of default behavior.  Any idea how to prevent this?

I suppose I should set padding that relates to div that is before navbar. Is there any way to do this?  My goal is to have picture then scroll it and see the rest of website. Then I want my navbar to become fixed and stay on top.

EDIT:
Here is my html:

```
<header>
    <a href="#sticky-menu" class="page-scroll">
        <div name="startSection" class="content startHandle" id="startPhoto" data-stellar-background-ratio="0">
            <img id="startHeader" class="col-md-8 col-xs-12" src="images/home_title.png">
        </div>
    </a>
</header>
<?php include 'include/fixed_menu.php' ?>
<div class="content container newAlbumSection" id="startContent">
further content...
</div>
```

fixed_menu.php:

```
<div id="sticky-menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav margins-navbar">
                    <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/bg/lc/">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/bg/lc/bio/">BIO</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/bg/lc/discography/">DISCOGRAPHY</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/bg/lc/press/">PRESS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/bg/lc/video">VIDEO</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/bg/lc/photo">PHOTO</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/bg/lc/contact">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

</div>
```

css:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.content {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#startPhoto {
      background: url("../images/home_photo.png") no-repeat;
      background-size: 100% 100%;
      height: 57em;
}

#startHeader{
      position: absolute;
      padding-top: 0;
      left: 0.5em;
      bottom: 0;
}
```

result:
http://bez-granic.eu/lc/

Comment: Could you create a demo or provide a link if it's live?

Comment: ok i'll edit my post in a minute

Comment: i've just added html css and link to my post

Comment: It looks like you could appreciate checking out jQuery's .toggleClass() http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: i knew .toggleClass(), i just didn't see any way to use it. I've used @Shikkediel solution which includes using .toggleClass(). Thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original question isn't too hard to solve, just switch some margin (or padding) on the content below with the same height as the menu along with it. And as suggested in the comments :

```
.topspace {
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```
$(function() {

var gate = $(window),
sticky = $('#sticky-menu'),
size = $('.startHandle').height(),
content = $('#startContent'),
fixed;

gate.on('load', function() {

// Timeout is for cached scroll position with Opera

    setTimeout(function() {

        if (gate.scrollTop() <= size) {
        sticky.addClass('navbar-static-top');
        fixed = false;
        }
        else {
        sticky.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        fixed = true;
        }
    }, 50);
})
.scroll(function() {

    if (gate.scrollTop() > size) {
    if (!fixed) {
    switchMenu();
    content.addClass('topspace');
    }
    }
    else {
    if (fixed) {
    switchMenu();
    content.removeClass('topspace');
    }
    }
});

function switchMenu() {

    sticky.toggleClass('navbar-fixed-top navbar-static-top');
    fixed = !fixed;
}
});
```

Adding a check to see if the switch has been made would be better too, otherwise it will keep trying to toggle the class on every scroll event. Don't mind me using my own coding conventions by the way...

But on my (Windows 7) machine there's another bug. Reaching the point where the sticky menu is switching, I'm prevented from scrolling any further. The page gets 'stuck' there, so to say. Don't see that in your post. Even stranger, when I open developer tools (and it is docked to the window) or resize to a smaller screen size the issue is gone.

I can look into that.

Comment: Wow what a great community!
Your solution worked - thank you!
About that bug... I've been unable to reproduce it... I've tried it on firefox, chrome and default browser (ubuntu). I also checked it on firefox and chrome (windows 8) and still no bug... Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Glad the code does the job in the live environment. The issue I described is odd but I suspect it might disappear by itself when you style the footer. Somehow that seems to be related - when I gave it a fixed height the problem was suddenly gone. Strange that it's apparently dependent on the machine that is used somehow. It doesn't seem like something to worry about too much though, considering the easy fix.

Comment: Yeah, I will work on footer. At first I thoguht it was a problem with file transfer (I develop on local server - much faster).
Issue is quite odd but I suppose it'll be alright in the end. Hopefuly :) Again - thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. If the site is finished you could always drop me a comment here (maybe include my name with an @ in front otherwise I might miss it) and I could check if all is working as expected. Cheers.