# Bar that starts at the bottom of the page, scrolls up and then sticks to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to reproduce an idea that I had in mind. It would be in one of those long scrolling page.

The navigation bar would start at the bottom of the initial screen. Once you start scrolling down, it scrolls up at the same rhythm, but once it reaches the top, it stays fixed. If you scroll back to the top, it goes back down to it's original position.

It would be something like this: http://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/xEAqC that stays fixed at the same number mark as you scroll, and then sticks to the top, unless you scroll back up to the number.

The sample code:

```js
$(document).on("ready", function() {

  sortTheFooterOut();

});

function sortTheFooterOut() {

  footer = $("#footer");

  $(window).on("scroll", function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {

      if (!footer.hasClass("fixed")) {
        footer.fadeOut(250, function() {

          footer.addClass("fixed").fadeIn(250);

        });
      }
    } else {
      footer.fadeOut(250, function() {

        footer.removeClass("fixed").fadeIn(250);

      });
    }

  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Light", "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  background: #008aca;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Footer Scroll</h1>
1
<br>2
<br>3
<br>4
<br>5
<br>6
<br>7
<br>8
<br>9
<br>10
<br>11
<br>12
<br>13
<br>14
<br>15
<br>16
<br>17
<br>18
<br>19
<br>20
<br>21
<br>22
<br>23
<br>24
<br>25
<br>26
<br>27
<br>28
<br>29
<br>30
<br>31
<br>32
<br>33
<br>34
<br>35
<br>36
<br>37
<br>38
<br>39
<br>40
<br>
<footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
```

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: @RikenShah - I'm with you... What is the OP asking? It seems as though he answered his own question with... his own question...

Comment: @RikenShah - A friend cleared this up for me, apparently, he just wants the opposite effect. Instead of the menu starting at the top, he wants it to start at the bottom and flip to the top as you scroll down.

Comment: @rockmandew Indeed, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, I guess?

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVNjGz?editors=001)

```
$(function() {

var gate = $(window),
footer = $('#footer'),
space;

gate.on('load resize', function() {

    clearTimeout(redraw);

    var redraw = setTimeout(function() {
    space = gate.height()-footer.outerHeight();
    sortTheFooterOut();
    }, 150);
})
.scroll(sortTheFooterOut);

function sortTheFooterOut() {

    var current = gate.scrollTop(),
    stuck = footer.hasClass('fixed');       

    if (current > space) {
    if (!stuck) {
    footer.addClass('fixed');
    }
    }
    else if (stuck) footer.removeClass('fixed');
}
});
```

Added a check to apply the class correctly when the user lands on the page when it has a cached scroll position. Especially Opera is stubborn with this - it repositions *after* the window onload event, hence the timeout. Also included some resize debouncing. For the combined event the timeout was made a bit longer than absolutely necessary for onload by itself.

Before I try to tackle the issue of overlapping content mentioned by rockmandew in the comments, some more info on the exact document structure would be desirable. Wouldn't want to waste time there... or overdo it on the scripting.

Comment: This solution works, to an extent - While you have successfully addressed the question and supplied an appropriate response. I don't think this solution is ideal because it is always covering up some list-items (i.e. I can't ever see #13 and #14). I assume that isn't desired.

Comment: I see what you mean, let me have a go at addressing that. Another tweak that's needed would be to check on page load for a cached scroll position and apply the appropriate class.

Comment: Good call on the cached scroll position; I'd be interested as to how you handle both of those issues - mostly the cached scroll position :p - If you need an extra pair of eyes, let me know.

Comment: Think I got some code for the cached position ready : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32670504/3168107. The other issue seems a bit trickier to solve, may need more than just script...

Comment: Woah! @Shikkediel is answering future questions before they're even asked :p Nice work, I will see if I can put it through some testing. As for the other issue, I agree, I think it is a little bit more tricky than we would like it to be. In addition, I think the solution would depend on how the developer would like it to function - because you could do a number of things.